# Embedded Node execute .node file

Tags: c++, node.js, n-api

I've built an embedded instance of Node using the Embed_Test example from the Node repository.
Using this instance, I am trying to execute some C++ code.
I have a generated .node and .dll, and I have webpack'd my Javascript file.
When I run,

```
node dist/bundle.js
```

It runs fine. However, when I start up my embedded NodeJS application and attempt to run bundle.js, I get the following error (it's as if it cannot load the .node file?):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'testCppCode' of undefined
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:154:2305
    at s.handle_request (evalmachine.<anonymous>:120:782)
    at s (evalmachine.<anonymous>:113:879)
    at p.dispatch (evalmachine.<anonymous>:113:901)
    at s.handle_request (evalmachine.<anonymous>:120:782)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:106:2533
    at Function.v.process_params (evalmachine.<anonymous>:106:3436)
    at g (evalmachine.<anonymous>:106:2476)
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:259:218
    at s.handle_request (evalmachine.<anonymous>:120:782)
```

This is my App.js, before a webpack:

```
var myArgs = process.argv.slice(2);
var ip = myArgs.length >= 1 ? myArgs[0] : "localhost";
var port = myArgs.length >= 2 ? myArgs[1] : "5555";

var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");

const express = require("express");
var addon = require("../build/Release/test.node");

const server = express();

server.get("/", (req, res) => {
  var res = addon.testCppCode("Sample", function (err, cpp) {
    var capabilitiesResult = cpp;
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error!");
      console.log(err);
      console.log(cpp);
    } else {
      console.log("Success!");
    }
  });
});
```

I've tried sticking the test.node and test.dll in the same folder as the embedded instance of node, I've tried putting it in the same dir as the webpack, I've tried sticking it in a relative dir to the embedded node (so it would be at ../build/Release/) -- but the error is always the same. What do I need to do in order to get it to "see" the .node file?